# How to manipulate a BLOB in Java?

Tags: java, blob

I have a DB procedure which returns a BLOB. Can anyone tell me how to manipulate the BLOB? Is there any specific API for this?

Comment: Such as the API for java.sql.Blob?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ***Is there any specific API for this ?***

Sure, the JDBC API.

- [Trail: JDBC™ Database Access](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/)

---

You get hold of the `Blob` instance just as you get hold of any value from a result set. You should then use the `get...`- and `set...` methods on this `Blob`.

Here you basically have two options:

- Work with a byte-array:

  1. Get hold of a `byte[]` containing the data through [`Blob.getBytes`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBytes%28long,%20int%29)
  2. Manipulate this byte-array
  3. Set it back using [`Blob.setBytes`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBytes%28long,%20byte[]%29).
- Work with `InputStream` / `OutputStream`:

  1. Get hold a an `InputStream` through [`Blob.getBinaryStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBinaryStream%28%29)
  2. Manipulate this stream as you see fit
  3. Use [`Blob.setBinaryStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBinaryStream%28long%29).

An alternative approach is to skip messing with `Blob` in the first place, and instead use the second approach (with streams) directly through the `ResultSet`-interface.

Comment: My experience is that `ResultSet.getBinaryStream()` is more robust than working with instances of `Blob`

Comment: @aioobe : Thanks for the responses. But can anyone tell me how 'ResultSet.getBinaryStream()' is robust compared to 'Blob.getBinaryStream' ?

Comment: If your driver supports `ResultSet.getBlob` and `Blob.getBinaryStream`, and you're fairly confident that you won't switch to another database, just go with the one you find most readable.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on which kind of blob contains (image, video) and it's extension.  I wrote a simple program to retrieve an image from DB and show it in JSP page.  Hope it helps.

JSP Page

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>                            
    <image src="blobAction"/> 
</body>
```

Servlet Page

```
byte[] imgData = blobDao.getInstance().getPhoto();
        response.setContentType("image/gif");
        OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
        o.write(imgData);
        o.flush();
        o.close();
```

Calling Procedure

```
public byte[] getPhoto() {

    byte[] imgData = null;
    Blob img = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        conn = getConnection();
        String sqlQ = "SELECT CONTENT_FILE FROM CONTENT where id = 'something';
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQ);

        while (rs.next()) {
            img = rs.getBlob("CONTENT_FILE");
            imgData = img.getBytes(1, (int) img.length());
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {           
        return imgData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Simple Java JDBC Api, you can get a [`java.sql.Blob`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) back from a [`ResultSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

1. `ResultSet.getBlob(index)` or
2. `ResultSet.getBlob(String columnName)`.

Both returns a `Blob`.

Once you get a `Blob`, you can get the `byte[]` back from the [`Blob.getBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBytes%28long,%20int%29) method or set using [`setBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBytes%28long,%20byte%5B%5D%29) method.

Update: Seeing that some Database driver vendors don't support `Blob`, you can use [`ResultSet.getBinaryStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream%28int%29).

Comment: Why pointless? The existence of a BLOB datatype in the database has nothing to do with the support by the driver. Not all **drivers** support `ResultSet.getBlob()` some only support `ResultSet.getInputStream()`

Comment: @All : Thanks guys for the responses. If getBlob() is not supported by all then which method is good to use ? Blob.getBinaryStream() ?

Comment: I usually do `ResultSet.getBytes()` and work with `byte[]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/rowset/serial/SerialBlob.html).

I'm using it in my SpringBoot & Angular4 application like this:

- get Base64String from Angular4 app
- decode Base64String to byte[]
- create SerialBlob like this: `SerialBlob serialBlob = new SerialBlob(byte[])`
- store it in the database with JpaRepository

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
public void Insert(Object obj){
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(byteArray);
            oos.writeObject(obj);
            PreparedStatement ps= conn1.prepareStatement("insert into vehiculos values(?)");    
            ps.setBytes(1, byteArray.toByteArray());  
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:al hacer un Insert");   
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void ShowData(){
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn1.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM vehiculos";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            Object obj;
            while(rs.next()){
                //Coche c = (Coche)rs.getBlob("coches");
                Blob blob = rs.getBlob("coches");
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(blob.getBinaryStream());
                obj = ois.readObject();
                System.out.println(obj.toString());
                System.out.println("");
                /*Blob blob = rs.getBlob("coches");
                byte[] data = blob.getBytes(1, (int)blob.length());*/
                
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:al consultar");
            ex.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    public void cerrar_Conexion (){
       
        try {  
        conn1.close();
      } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR:al cerrar la conexión");
            ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```